# TypedDict didn't raise unexpected key error

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror, typeddict

According to the [TypedDict documentation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0589/#supported-and-unsupported-operations), the following code should raise:

> error: Unexpected key 'director'

```
from typing import TypedDict

class Movie(TypedDict):
    name: str
    year: int

m: Movie = dict(
    name='Alien',
    year=1979,
    director='Ridley Scott')
```

But nothing happened. I can still query the "director" field. Why is that?

```
print(m["director"])
```

> Ridley Scott

Comment: did you find any solution for this? I'm having the exact same problem...

Comment: same issue here